# passing date parameter inside python subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, airflow

I'm running a command in python subprocess.Popen. The below line works fine!

```
subprocess.Popen(["airflow", "db", "clean", "--verbose", "--clean-before-timestamp", "2022-07-29"])
```

However, I'm trying to replace the date with a variable to go back in the past from the current date something like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(["airflow", "db", "clean", "--verbose", "--clean-before-timestamp", "time_diff"])
```

And the get time_diff like this :

```
import datetime as DT
today = DT.date.today()
time_diff = today - DT.timedelta(days=30)


try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(["airflow", "db", "clean", "--verbose", "--clean-before-timestamp", "time_diff"])
    while p.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(5)
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc(), flush=True)
```

But the above code gives an error.

command error: argument --clean-before-timestamp: invalid parse value: 'time_diff'

How can I get the date variable there without having to hard code it as I will be running a cronjob on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the datetime object into a string using [stftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) before passing it to `Popen`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["airflow", "db", "clean", "--verbose", "--clean-before-timestamp", time_diff.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")])
```

Answer (score 1):

The @rdas answer can solve your problem, but where you are trying to use the airflow CLI from airflow, I would like to suggest a better method than `subprocess` or `BashOperator`.

Airflow CLI is developped by python, and it calls python methods which you can call easily from airflow, for example the command `airflow db clean` calls the method [run_cleanup](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/27e2101f6ee5567b2843cbccf1dca0b0e7c96186/airflow/utils/db_cleanup.py#L310), which you can call to clean the db without a complex bash commands call, and you will have python exceptions for the problems.

```py
import pendulum
from airflow.utils.db_cleanup import run_cleanup

run_cleanup(clean_before_timestamp=pendulum.today() - pendulum.duration(days=30), verbose=True, confirm=False)
```

It might sound a little complicated, but it's better for long-term use cases.